# Cannot connect visualvm to a custom openjdk7 variant

Tags: java, visualvm

I have a locally built openjdk7 with a few modifications I made centered around the sun.mic.unsafe interface. When attempting to use visualvm to connect to an application running over said jvm I'm getting grayed out CPU graph and missing threads tab with the ominous "Not supported for this JVM" message. 
I wonder what am I missing in my JVM that prevents using visualvm?
This is my invocation:

```
/visualvm_138/bin/visualvm --jdkhome /home/user/openjdk/javaFTM/v0.3/j2sdk-image
```

Here is the ls from my custom openjdk:

```
ASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION  bin  demo  include  jre  lib  LICENSE  man  release  sample  src.zip  THIRD_PARTY_README
```

Any ideas?
Thanks
Tomer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer turns out to be much simpler than I thought - just use the j2sdk-server-image folder and not the j2sdk-image and you can connect plain-ol visualvm to the non-standard openjdk. 
Voila